# Injecting kafkatopic from application.properties to KafkfaListener

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have this in my application properties

```
mytopic.topic="testtopic"
```

On the `@Kafkalistener` when I try below, the topic is not getting injected

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "${mytopic.topic}")
```

It fails as
`aused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Topic(s) ["testtopic"] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true`

Seems it is reading it as a list or something? How do I inject it from config?

Comment: [It is being injected](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/receiving-messages/listener-annotation.html#annotation-properties). The error instead seems to say that topic doesn't exist on the cluster, and `missingTopicsFatal==true`

Comment: I know that error message says that, but the topic exists because if I use the exact string directly, the code works.

Comment: It's possible that check using `localhost:9092`. I assume you are connecting to a remote cluster. The config `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` would set all clients rather than only consumer

Comment: No, that is not true. You can try this foryourself if you suspect so. Please do not taint the thread with random suggestions